# Can a moderator or higher up delete a question of mine?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198627/what-is-the-code-on-stackoverflow-page-not-found-pages-closed

Call me a perfectionist (aren't all programmers) but I dislike having a closed question on my profile. The red is... ugly.

Can it be totally removed please?

Here is my [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102482/finglas) profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine -- in the future, it's more expedient to flag your question for moderator attention using the flag menu and explain what you want done.

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. I wasn't sure whether or not to flag.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your question will be deleted because deletions are reserved for special circumstances.

Closed questions are just that, close. Yours was actually migrated.

In short, there isn't a reason to delete it, other then your request.

Comment: I understand the migrating. Why it's linked to my SO profile is the issue. If it's not even on SO anymore I don't see why it's still linked there.

Comment: Because you asked it.